# How to create an Inbox Rule with message header dkim=fail _AND_ dmarc=fail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, headers

Is there a way to create an *Outlook 365* `Inbox Rule` that will fire only if in the *message header Authentication-Results*, there are *dkim=fail **AND** dmarc=fail*?

When I define the following:
[image: Rule definition]

the resulting rule I get is:

[image: Rule]

Namely, I don't get *dkim=fail **AND** dmarc=fail* but *dkim=fail **OR** dmarc=fail*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test and research, i cannot create a rule that meets both criteria. I'm afraid that you need to create two rules for the two criteria.

Comment: Thanks @Christy, but I need a rule that will `fire` only if _both_ conditions are true, not if _either_ is true.